# Why "read 2 files and return diff" doesn't work in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, readfile

I need a function that takes 2 file names, reads them and returns a diff. Here is what I wrote, but it does return boolean as I need.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const util = require('util')

const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile)
const access = util.promisify(fs.access)

/**
 * if exists, read the file (async)
 * @param {*} fileName
 * @returns Promise that if resolved will produce file contents
 */

async function 
verifyAndRead (fileName) {
    let _txt = null
    try {
        await access(fileName)
        .then(() => readFile(fileName))
        .then((txt) => _txt = txt.toString())
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(`verifyAndRead(): ${e.stack}`)
    }
    // console.log(`foo(): ${_txt}`)
    return _txt
}

async function 
match (file1, file2) {
    // logger.trace(`match ('${file1}', '${file2}')`)

    let a = await verifyAndRead(f1)
    let b = await verifyAndRead(f2)

    return a === b
}
```

In match(), both a and b are resolved. i.e. console.log() prints the contents of the file/s, so they are available, so the return statement should return the diff (true/false) but it returns a Promise. Why?
I need a boolean. This function is part of an API/module that will be used by other users to develop test cases/scripts and who are not javascript developers primarily, so I need to keep things simple for them. Typical use of this would be

`if (match(<expected_output>, <current_output>)) {
    logger.log('Test passed.')
}`

and I would like to avoid testers having to use 'await' or 'then()' etc. in their scripts.

Because `a === b` returns a Promise, I further tried to replace

`return a === b` with

```
let c = await (() => {
    a === b
})()

return c
```

hoping to get a boolean, but that didn't help either.

After trying many things, it looks like the only way to do it is to read the files Synchronously and take a diff, but I'd like to do it the Node.js way as much as I can.

Does anyone know if/how it can be done async'ly? Am I missing something?

Comment: `async` functions always return `Promise`s. There's no way for synchronous program flow to somehow wait for something asynchronous (without some really bad hacks). Embrace it and call `.then` on the `Promise` to get the value it resolves to.

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of avoiding using 'await' or 'then()', you should use feature of promises. try to change match function like this:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const util = require('util')

const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile)
const access = util.promisify(fs.access)

async function
verifyAndRead (fileName) {
    let _txt = null
    try {
        await access(fileName)
            .then(() => readFile(fileName))
            .then((txt) => _txt = txt.toString())
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(`verifyAndRead(): ${e.stack}`)
    }
    return _txt
}

async function match (f1, f2) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        Promise.all([verifyAndRead(f1), verifyAndRead(f2)]).then((values) => {
            resolve(values[0] === values[1]);
        });
    });
}

match('package.json', 'package-lock.json').then((result) => {
    if (result) {
        // if match do your stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: wrapping `Promise.all()` in a `new promise` was a thing I missed, hence I was  getting `{}` or `undefined` in the calling function.

Comment: Please see live example https://repl.it/repls/EagerUnderstatedPublishing. still getting error? which line/var?

Comment: No No not anymore, not with your solution.. I *was* getting different values initially when I was experimenting before I posted the question. Thx.